# variable cannot be modified in another class

Tags: class, variables, swift

am trying to modify a variable in another class, but it doesn't change.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var t = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        t = 9
        var pp = action().test()
        println(pp) // got “2” here

}
```

the above should print "10" , but it shows "2".

another swift file:

```
class action {

    var k = ViewController().t

        func test()->Int{

            k++

            return k

        }

}
```

Anything I made wrong? 
Thnaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a class with properties, and create an instance of that class, properties are bound to the class instance and not the class type. So if you create 2 instances of the same class their properties are independent, so if you change a property in one instance, that won't affect the same property in the other instance.

**Note**: by convention, in swift type names always start in uppercase, so I have renamed `action` to `Action` in my code.

Your code isn't working as expected because in the `Action` class you are creating a new instance of `ViewController`:

```
var k = ViewController().t
```

which has no relationship with the instance used to instantiate `Action` - so the new instance will have its `t` property set to 1.

The correct way to fix it is to pass the view controller instance to `Action`, and let it work on that instance.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var t = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        t = 9

        var action = Action(viewController: self)
        var pp = action.test()
        println(pp) // got “2” here
    }
}

class Action {
    var k: Int

    init(viewController: ViewController) {
        self.k = viewController.t
    }

    func test()->Int{
        k++
        return k            
    }
}
```

The above code should give an indication of what's wrong with your code, but it can be written in a better way. `Action` doesn't really need the `ViewController` instance, it just needs an integer passed in to its initializer, so a better way to achieve the same result is by modifying the code as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var t = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        t = 9

        var action = Action(t: self.t)
        var pp = action.test()
        println(pp) // got “2” here
    }
}

class Action {
    var k: Int

    init(t: Int) {
        self.k = t
    }

    func test()->Int{
        k++
        return k            
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine and it did fit my need. @Antonio Thanks.